# a 2×2 matrix that has a power equal to the identity and an eigenvalue in F_p, but is not diagonalizable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form

The problem states: Find a 2×2 matrix with entries in $\mathbb{F}_p$ that has a power equal to the identity and an eigenvalue in $\mathbb{F}_p$, but is not diagonalizable. I have found some examples with specific p, but don't know how to generalize them to any prime number p.

Comment: What are your examples?

Comment: The matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, where $\mathbb{F}_p=\mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Great - @martini's answer... $(I+N)^n = 0$, for what $n$?

Comment: I know it depends on p but couldn't figure out how to represent it...

Comment: Ah I think understand... Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - for not answering - I was away from my computer - but if you've understood it...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Have a look at $$ A := \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} =: \mathrm{Id} + N $$
$A$ is surely not diagonalizable, but has $1$ as an eigenvalue. Now look at powers of $A$ (the power that is the identity will depend on $p$).

Comment: I got your idea... Thanks!